# Best way to implment timeout for a while loop

Tags: python, time

I have a while loop

```
while somecondition:
    dostuff
```

(Sorry. It is hard to give an executable example as this is part of a larger project).

Most of the time the condition is met after a short while and the loop expires. But sometimes the condition will never be met. How can I best catch such cases? Is a timer the best option? How can I implement it best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wait for an hour example

```
from datetime import timedelta
delete_TO = 1
wait_until = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=delete_TO)
break_loop = False
while not break_loop:
     do-your loop-stuff
     if wait_until < datetime.now() or somecondition:
          break_loop = True
```

(edited: wait_until must be smaller than datetime.now() )

Answer (score 12):

You can use a timeout using SIGALRM. Here's a little program that demonstrates it.

```
import sys

import time
import signal


class TimeoutError(Exception):
    pass

def _sig_alarm(sig, tb):
    raise TimeoutError("timeout")

def main(argv):
    timeout = 7
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _sig_alarm)
    try:
        signal.alarm(timeout)
        while True:
            print("sleeping...")
            time.sleep(1)
    except TimeoutError:
        pass
    print("Out of loop.")



main(sys.argv)
```

This sets up a signal handler that simply raises a custom exception (but you can use any), and then catches it.

Comment: This is also implemented as a package, called `interruptingcow` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/interruptingcow) ... yes, I love the name too.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is

```
from datetime import timedelta
delete_TO = 1
wait_until = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=delete_TO)
break_loop = False
while not break_loop:
     do-your loop-stuff
     if wait_until < datetime.now() or somecondition:
          break_loop = True
```

This code is copy pasted from @ohad_the_lad (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2468201/ohad-the-lad) answer, but it fixes the unintentional bug where the loop exits if wait_until is greater than datetime.now() which will always happen.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a for loop? Or you can implement something like timer=0 an increment it every time you pass the loop. For example if you wanted to break after 100 iterations you could write an if statement. If timer == 100 then break.